# Search Bar coding for multiple keywords when only 1 matches

Tags: php, mysql, searchbar, keyword-search

So I have looked around the internet and actually signed up to this site since i find most my google searches wind me up here. I am almost done making my website and I used a template that I expanded. It has a search bar on it that wasn't functioning. I have got it working mostly. the problem I am having is that when I put in a keyword that MySQL has it works fine, when I put in a lone keyword that I know doesn't exist it give a proper no results response. Now my problem is when you mix the 2 up it errors out the database. Here is my php code that I've put together so far...

```
    <?php
$db = mysqli_connect('host','username','password')
or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');
$keyword = $_GET['keyword'];
$terms = explode(" ", $keyword);

$query = "SELECT * FROM searchresults WHERE ";

foreach ($terms as $each) {

    $i=0;
    if ($i == 0)
    $query .= "pagebody LIKE  '%$each%' ";
    else
    $query .= " OR pagebody LIKE  '%$each%' ";

}

mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');

$result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);


if ($row > 0) {

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $title = $row['title'];
        $description = $row['description'];
        $pagebody = $row['pagebody'];
        $link = $row['link'];


        echo "<h2><a href='$link'>$title</a></h2></br>
        $description<br/><br/>";
    }
}   else 
echo "No results found for.\"<b>$keyword</b>\"";
?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I need to figure out how to make it so that if any of the keywords aren't recognized that it doesn't error out.

Comment: lol yes I caught that as I was re reading my code thank you I'm changing them now

Comment: You are executing your query twice, and fetching twice which causes your results to start on the second row. The bug you are describing is if 1 keyword is present and the other is not you want no results, or you get back no results? (Also SQL injection issue as previously noted (removing that comment though))

Comment: thanks for your reply. I'm pretty new to MYSQL with a crash learning curve as Ive been leaving the search bar last while creating my simple website. I'll look into the SQL injection part as well. Is the double query from the foreach separation on the else statement? I didnt realize that as I dont get double results when the keyword works.

Comment: Take out `mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');` and just do `$result = mysqli_query($db, $query) or die('Error querying database.');` if it `die`s your script will stop anyway. The take out the `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);` and use the row count function. I'm not sure what behavior you are seeing currently.. actually answer below seems like it will address it.. or at least the start of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This won't fix the problems you have escaping your user input, but to answer your question in resolving the search error; your original code is keeping $i as equalling 0 through each iteration of the foreach loop so the query is coming out as:

```
SELECT * FROM searchresults WHERE pagebody LIKE '%$each%' pagebody LIKE '%$each%' pagebody LIKE '%$each%'
```

You need to modify the following lines:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM searchresults WHERE ";

foreach ($terms as $each) {

    $i=0;
    if ($i == 0)
    $query .= "pagebody LIKE  '%$each%' ";
    else
    $query .= " OR pagebody LIKE  '%$each%' ";

}
```

change that to:

```
$i=0;
$query = "SELECT * FROM searchresults WHERE";

foreach ($terms as $each) {
  if($i == 0){
    $query .= " pagebody LIKE '%$each%'";
  }else{
    $query .= " OR pagebody LIKE  '%$each%'";
  }
$i++;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your input. when I was first writing that part I actually had the $i variable as $i++ instead of $i=0 but I was reading forums working bugs out and I seen a comment elsewhere that suggested making it $i=0 I will adjust it tomorrow. Thank you for your time